# How to prevent redundant files when using Wordpress on Openshift

Tags: wordpress, openshift-online-2

I am running a Wordpress site on OpenShift that has an uploaded folder size of about 200mbs. This should be well under the limits for the free account, however, it appears to copy it a few times in order to deploy giving me a du like this...

```
216K    php
44M mysql
222M    git
246M    app-deployments
268M    app-root
```

**Side Note**

Because my uploads are so large and change a lot I am "checking in" my uploads by adding it to .openshift/uploads and adding the following to my deploy.

```
# linked directly to Git in order to cut down on space.
ln -sf ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}uploads   ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}.openshift/uploads
```

**Back to the core problem**

Is there something else I can add/configure to lower the amount of duplicate files more?

Comment: https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202398490-Persistant-storage-for-OpenShift-applications

Comment: Thanks but that won't work for me I would still like to be able to access them (and version them) via the git repo. That sounds like you would have to ftp (or copy?) into the data directory. Also realized my code was bad at first but after fixing still seems to be x3